# Install Ubuntu on Dell Precision 5510

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, ssd

I get a major problem when trying to install Ubuntu. The laptop has a Samsung NVMe SSD, but Ubuntu 16.04 does not recognize it. Instead it suggests to install it on the USB drive itself (see screenshot).

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: At UEFI do you have settings for changing the mode from RAID to AHCI? If so, change it.

Comment: Are you trying to install in dual boot with Windows? If not, create a new partition table using gparted.

Comment: In BIOS I changed from RAID to Disabled, but Windows wont boot, and yes, I want dual boot

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following steps before running the ubuntu installer:

1. If you have a instance of windows 8/10 running disable the Windows
   Fast boot.look at the below link for instructions on disabling fast
   boot:

   http://acer-in.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37059/~/windows-10%3A-enable-or-disable-fast-startup
2. In the bios setting disable secure boot.

Try to re run the ubuntu installation procedure after making the above suggest changes.

Comment: Did not help recognizing the SSD :( it shows me only /dev/sda with the 16GB USB